# Firebase configuration error while trying to run a React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I'm attempting to use Firebase in my react app, but when I try to do something I get this error:

> Firebase: Need to provide options, when not being deployed to hosting via source. (app/no-options).

My firebase.js code is this (I'll censor the data):

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  databaseURL: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

Obviously the data is inside the strings

I've tried to run firebase in my react app, but I'm getting a error.

Comment: You can follow This: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59031115/how-to-initiate-firebase-analytics-to-work-on-web

Comment: That's not the same problem I'm getting